# push method in a loop causing array inside of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have two arrays, one full of links and another one of domains of which shall be removed from the first array.

```
array1 = [ http://www.linkone.com, https://www.linktwo.com, ... ]
array2 = [ 'linkone' ]
```

The second array does not have the format of a URL, I've done this by doing the following:

```
for (let a2 of array2) {
  clearedUrls.push(_.pull(array1, `https?:\/\/www.${a2}.*`))
}
```

It worked, but the output of `clearedUrls` contains array inside of array:

```
[
  'https://www.foo.com',
  'https://www.foo.com',
  'https://www.foo.com',
  'https://www.foo.com',
  [
    'https://www.foo.com',
    'https://www.foo.com',
    'https://www.foo.com',
  ],
  [ ... ]
]
```

I know it's because every iteration it will `push`. I'd like to know a better way to loop over the `array2`, remove the URLs from `array`, and return the array with only links inside, no more arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat?v=example) instead of `push`:

```
clearedUrls = clearedUrls.concat(_.pull(array1, `https?:\/\/www.${a2}.*`))
```